# Array-3 fix45 coding bat

Tags: java, arrays

i am trying to solve an Array problem on coding bat the assignment is

> Return an array that contains exactly the same numbers as the given array, but rearranged so that every 4 is immediately followed by a 5. Do not move the 4's, but every other number may move. The array contains the same number of 4's and 5's, and every 4 has a number after it that is not a 4. In this version, 5's may appear anywhere in the original array.

my code passes all the tests except the one below

```
([4, 9, 4, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 5]) → [4, 5, 4, 5, 9, 9, 4, 5, 9]
```

here is my code

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {
      int val =0, lastF = 0, var;
      for (int i =0; i < nums.length-1; i++)
        if (nums[i] == 4){
          var = i+1;
          for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++)
            if ((nums[j] == 5) && (j >= lastF && j != var)){
              lastF =j;
              val = nums[i+1];
              nums[i+1] = nums[j];
              nums[j] = val;
            }
        }
      return nums;
    }
```

my code returns

```
[4, 5, 4, 5, 9, 5, 4, 9, 9]
```

if anyone can help me figure out what i need to tweak to make it pass this last test thank you

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger and see for yourself.

Comment: i know what the issue is that lastF variable becomes greater that j which is the index  that searches for the number 5 i try setting a break statement and even making lastF = 0 each loop but that does not work @PM77-1

Comment: If you know what's wrong, what stops you from fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in one while loop just by using two flags and two pointers!

```
public int[] fix45(int[] nums) {


      int start = 0;
      int end = nums.length-1;

      boolean is4 = false;
      boolean is5 = false;


      while( start < nums.length ){

        if(nums[start] == 4 && nums[start+1]!=5){
          is4 = true;
        }

        if(nums[end] == 5 && (end == 0 || (end-1>=0 && nums[end-1]!=4))){
          is5 = true;
        }


        if(is4 && is5){
          int temp = nums[start+1];
          nums[start+1] = nums[end];
          nums[end] = temp;

          is4 = false;
          is5 = false;
          end = nums.length-1;
        }



        if(is4){
          end--;
          continue;
        }

        start++;
      }
      return nums;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag so your second loop stops iterating when it finds the next element 5. Also instead of iterating from 0 on the second loop you could iterate from i instead so it becomes more efficient.

```
    boolean isFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 4) {
            var = i + 1;
            for (int j = i; j < nums.length && !isFound ; j++) {
                if ((nums[j] == 5) && (j >= lastF && j != var)) {
                    lastF = j;
                    val = nums[i + 1];
                    nums[i + 1] = nums[j];
                    nums[j] = val;
                    isFound = true;
                }
            }
            isFound = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting lastF to j when you should set it to i+2. You are replacing i+1 with j so you should set lastF to one after i+1(i+2) instead of j. Also, you have to start the j-forloop at lastF.

It should look like this:

```
int val =0, lastF = 0, var;
for (int i =0; i < nums.length; i++)
if (nums[i] == 4){
          var = i+1;
          for (int j = lastF; j < nums.length; j++)
            if ((nums[j] == 5) && (j >= lastF && j != var)){
              lastF =i+2;
              val = nums[i+1];
              nums[i+1] = nums[j];
              nums[j] = val;
            }
        }
```

Comment: hey your code pass that particular test but fails these two test case            5, 5, 4, 1, 4, 1 it returns  1, 5, 4, 5, 4, 1 instead of 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 5  the 2nd case is 5, 4, 5, 4, 1 it returns 5, 4, 5, 4, 1 instead of 1, 4, 5, 4, 5 but it passes the rest

Comment: Did you try the other answer?

Comment: No I mean @anto004 also answered has answered did you try his code?

Comment: I tried the other way it did not work. I will keep trying though.

Comment: What I would suggest is to move all data other than 4 or 5 to the end and then from there you can sort the 4 and 5s easier.